# Finding probabilities of joint density functions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, density-function

I am working on a problem and am a bit confused.

The problem: Consider (X,Y) with density p(x,y) = 24xy on

0$\le$x$\le$1

0$\le$y$\le$1

0$\le$x+y$\le$1

Find: P(X$\le$.5 | Y$\ge$.5)

What I have done so far:

P(X$\le$.5 | Y$\ge$.5) = $P(X\le.5) \over P(Y\ge.5)$

I imagine the setup might look something along the lines of:

P(X$\le.5$) = 1 - $\int_{.5}^1$ $\int_{.5}^1$ 24xy d(x) d(y)

I am unsure how to determine the integral set ups however.

Comment: You need to double check the definition of conditional probability, the event inside the probability in the numerator is the intersection of two events. When you actually setting up the integral for calculation, you must consider all the bounds given in the support carefully. You can try to picture the two-dimensional support like this which will help you to form the correct bound.

Comment: The integral of 24xy; being seperable, is simply 6 x^2 y^2 over the limits.

Answer (score 0):

As BGM has said you have been asked to find the *conditional* probability, i.e. given Y > 0.5 what is the probability X < 0.5. However, there is no indication that the two variables are in any way dependant on each other. Maybe they are? This would make sense but necessitate an approach that we need more information for.

It is more likely you have been asked for the joint probability, i.e. P(X<0.5,Y>0.5) no vertical bar. In this case, yes, you want to integrate 24xy over the specified limits, but wait a minute does an integration of the density over the entire space = 1? It turns out it doesn't. You will have to normalise it by dividing by this value.

A final note is that in mathematics case matters X does not necessarily = x. Has something been left out or mistyped?

Comment: The question is about conditional probability not joint probability.

Comment: Maybe so, but you have provided utterly no information on how X is in any way conditional on Y. X and Y are not even defined.